# how to alter schema by inserting a new column in hive

Tags: hive, alter-table

I have a hive table stored on the cluster. I want to modify it by adding a new column, and have the old columns data with the data of the new column added from another table. Is there a way to do it without recreating the table?

the old schema looks like:

```
create external table XXX
(item_id bigint,
start_dt string,
end_dt string,
title string,
subtitle string,
description string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n'
stored as textfile
location '/user/me/XXX';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using below syntax.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
  [PARTITION partition_spec]                 -- (Note: Hive 0.14.0 and later)
  ADD|REPLACE COLUMNS (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)
  [CASCADE|RESTRICT] -- (Note: Hive 0.15.0 and later)
```